# json_encode problem

Tags: php, json

This has got me completely stumped:

```
print_r($json);
echo json_encode($json);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [query] => dia
    [suggestions] => Array
        (
            [0] => Diana Johnson
            [1] => Diane Abbott
        )

)
{"query":"dia","suggestions":[null,null]}
```

What on earth is going wrong?

**edit** Just to add to the general wtf-ery of this, here's another sample:

```
Array
(
    [query] => david
    [suggestions] => Array
        (
            [0] => David Cameron
            [1] => David Amess
            [2] => David Anderson
            [3] => David Blunkett
            [4] => David Burrowes
        )

)
{"query":"david","suggestions":["David Cameron",null,null,null,null]}
```

Comment: Are you 100% positive that everything in `$json` is valid UTF-8?

Comment: It's all being hauled out of the same table of the same database. Is there any reason it wouldn't be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an autocomplete script. I assume your results are loaded from a database, are you sure they're utf-8? If you cannot replicate this functionality by hardcoding the array, then it's probably an encoding issue.

According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php, "This function only works with UTF-8 encoded data."

You can also use http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php to see the last error.

Comment: I'm only on 5.2 so no `json_last_error`. If the data isn't in UTF-8 (the collation on the table it's in is UTF-8) then how do I go about converting it?

Comment: mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8')

Comment: We can tell pretty quickly if it's UTF8 or not by inspecting the bytes.  What's the output of `echo rawurlencode($json['suggestions'][0]);`?

Comment: `David%20Cameron`, but the next is `David%A0Amess`. Looks like that is the problem, so what can I do? I just exported and re-imported the table via a utf-8 text document, that didn't help.

Comment: `0xA0` is not a valid UTF-8 sequence -- it's a Windows-1252 non-breaking space.  In UTF-8, that character is represented by `0xC2` `0xA0`.  However, even if it was choking over that mistake, I'd only expect David Amess to be missing from the output.  David Cameron looks just fine...

Comment: @Peeter The query executed successfully but there's no change in what I'm getting back. Do I have to run it every time I want to make a query?

Comment: @Charles I've got all the data in a Notepad++ document. The 'Convert to UTF-8' command doesn't seem to help, is there some other way to convert the data?

Comment: I've posted my thoughts in a new answer, I needed formatting options that the comments box won't work with.

Answer (score 3):

I'm posting this as an answer because I need the full formatting abilities of the normal answer box.

Yeah, it's UTF-8 all right.  From the PHP interactive prompt:

```
php > $david = urldecode('David%A0Amess');
php > echo json_encode($david);
null
php > $david = urldecode('David%20Amess');
php > echo json_encode($david);
"David Amess"
php > $david = urldecode('David%c2%a0Amess');
php > echo json_encode($david);
"David\u00a0Amess"
```

So, we can *assume* that you're dealing with [either ISO-8859 or Windows-1252, given that we're dealing with a broken NBSP.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Encodings)  We can fix this with [`iconv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php):

```
php > $david = urldecode('David%A0Amess');
php > $david_converted = iconv('Windows-1252', 'UTF-8', $david);
php > echo json_encode($david_converted);
"David\u00a0Amess"
```

So, this means that you are going to need to *not trust* what you're pulling out of MySQL, assuming you've done the `SET NAMES` thing.  Clearly something has gone awry when you were inserting data.  You probably weren't giving MySQL well-formed UTF-8, and it stupidly did not complain.  (If you were using other, smarter, more correct databases, and tried to insert the unencoded NBSP, they would have rejected the input.)